# Windows Media Encoder based application deployment issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-media-encoder

If I develop my application based on Windows Media Encoder 9 Series SDK, and I am using C# + .Net 2.0 + VSTS 2008, how to deploy all necessary dependent files (the ones from Windows Media Encoder 9 and Windows Media Encoder 9 SDK) to another computer without installaing Windows Media Encoder 9 on the target computer?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Setup project, just select the necessary DLLs to be included with your setup.

Are you using OneClick deployment? If so, you can use the Prerequisites screen or simply select the necessary files to include in the Application files screen (both in the Publish tab of your project properties).

Comment: If I need some COM component, and Setup project will automatically register COM for me?

Comment: Not automatically, you can find more info on that here:
 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307367

Comment: My current issue is, I need to find out the dependent COM component from WME or WME SDK, any ideas how to do that?